# Display specific property of an object using string interpolation

Tags: angular

I need to display a property by string interpolation but it doesn't work. It seems everything is fine but I couldn't figure out why it doesn't work. Additionally the object `@Inputed()` to child component from parent.

```html
<mat-panel-description>
  {{personnelEvaluationList.maxPoint}}
  <mat-icon color="primary">timeline</mat-icon>
 </mat-panel-description>
```

and the ts parent code is:

```js
personnelEvaluationList: PersonnelEvaluation[] = [];

getEvaluationPersonnel(req: PersonnelEvaluationRequest) {
        this.isLoading = true;
        this.route.queryParamMap.subscribe(r => {
            this.personnelDetailApiService
                .getEvaluationPersonnel(req)
                .subscribe(res => {
                    this.personnelEvaluationList = (res.result);
                    this.isLoading = false;
                },
                    catchError((err) => {
                        this.snackBar.open('', null, {
                            duration: 5000
                        });
                        return throwError(err);
                    })
                );
        });
}
```

and the `evaluationPersonnelList` inputed to child and this is the child ts file

```js
@Input() personnelEvaluationList: PersonnelEvaluation;
```

and this is the parent template

```html
<app-personnel-details-list [personnelProfile]='personnelProfile' 
                  [personnelEvaluationList]='personnelEvaluationList'
                  [personnelVoiceOfCustomersList]='personnelVoiceOfCustomersList' 
                  [personnelAssessmentList]='personnelAssessmentList'>
</app-personnel-details-list>
```

Comment: I'm assuming {{personnelEvaluationList?.maxPoint}} since i see no ngIf to await the result before showing the childcomponent. Yet I cannot be sure, since you don't show the error it's displaying.

Comment: @LotteLemmens I tried this but didn't display anything yet, and I don't show an error because it doesn't have an error

Comment: In parent code, you state personnelEvaluationList is a list (type + [ ]), yet your input states type, no list ([ ]). Could it be a mismapping there?

Comment: If I changed to a list type in child component it returns such an error like this.          **Identifier 'maxPoint' is not defined. 'PersonnelEvaluation[]' does not contain such a member**     `{{personnelEvaluationList.maxPoint}}`

Comment: Now you should be able to loop over your list and then read the maxPoint for each item. 
<span ngFor="let p of personnelEvaluationList>{{p.maxPoint}}</span>

Comment: @LotteLemmens You're right, I did it and got the data I want but I want to access the maxPoint property outside the loop and that was the reason I wrote that code  {{personnelEvaluationList.maxPoint}}

Comment: `                <div *ngFor="let evaluation of personnelEvaluationList">
                    <div class="row around-xs">
                        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                            {{evaluation.month}}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div> `

Comment: This loop works fine but I can't access to none of those properties inside the list from outside the loop.

Comment: Angular will not know which item it should use to get these properties. 2 options: 
1. change the backend call to retrun a single object containing the properties you need
2. use the index of your list to read a property (ex. personnelEvelualtionList[0].month)

Comment: @LotteLemmens The first solution seems better and more logical.